# Pandas: Find Users with 2 Interactions In 4 Days

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame, `df`, with the following columns:

`user_id, date_of_visit`

I want to find all `user_id`s who visited at least twice in any 4 day window.  So if I had:

`user_id, date_of_visit`

`1, 1/4/15`

`1, 1/6/15`

`2, 1/4/15`

`2, 1/12/15`

`2, 1/23/15`

Then my function would return `[1]`

I could just go through each row, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to leverage Pandas.  Maybe something with:

`df.groupby('user_id')...`?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you make your example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `rolling` within `filter`

```
#df.date_of_visit=pd.to_datetime(df.date_of_visit)

df.groupby('user_id').filter(lambda x : x.set_index('date_of_visit').rolling('4d').count().gt(1).any()).user_id.unique()
Out[525]: array([1], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I used your approach but get `TypeError: filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool` . Happy to provide a reproducible example if helpful